# ffmpeg is looping / hanging up

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that i created from 3 other videos (merged them with FFMPEG).
Video Plays fine, but when i try to also add an watermark overlay on the video file i created it start to loop. And if i force it to close the output will be of one movie only.

I have 3 video files they have diffrent ScreenResulutions.
I merg those 3 video files in FFMPEG with this command via commandline

```
ffmpeg -i  "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts|intermediate3.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc myoutputfile.mp4
```

The out put works fine all 3 movies are merged, and i can play it like normal.

Now i try to ad a water mark to this new created video file.

```
ffmpeg -i mainmovie.ts -i mywatermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10:enable='lt(mod((t\\),20),7)'" WatermarkedVideoFile.mp4
```

The issue here is that it starts to loop seems like it hangs on the first 6 secounds and this seems to be the video that was in intermediate1.ts so i  think the issue is that the 3 files i merged to one video file may have diffrent Resulutions and this is why the overlay script dont work proper.

So my question is can i re-encode it somehow and force it so it will have same resulution while keeping aspect ratio?

Comment: If the videos have different aspect ratios, then that'll remain true after rescaling. Padding will be needed in that case.

Comment: @Mulvya i'm fine with different aspect ratios in my video but it seems like when i try to add a watermark it will loop once it change aspect ratio within the same video or something.

Comment: Why not add watermark to `myoutputfile.mp4` instead of the shown other `-i mainmovie.ts`?

Comment: Does this work as a test? `ffmpeg -i myoutputfile.mp4 -i mywatermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" my_video_logo.mp4`

Comment: @VC.One i have tested without .ts as well. I get same kind of error
This is what happens.
http://recordit.co/Aqx9smDDLX

When i use a normal video file it works fine. But the files that i just merged does not work and it gotta be something with the resulution or similar. One way to solve it is to watermark them before i merg them but it would be nice to learn how to avoid this error.